# Valums file uploader issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Valumes doesn't show UPLOAD button under Firefox (MVC3 Project).

It works fine under: IE, Chrome

I am going to kill myself but I don't understand why is it?

ANYYY CLUUU pleaseeee!

[image]

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/valums/FileUploader.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="fileUploader">
        <noscript>
            <p>
               Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
           <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
         </noscript>
</div>
```

.................

```
var button = $('#fileUploader')[0];
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
          element: button,
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
          sizeLimit: 2147483647,
          action: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
          multiple: false,
          onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
          var uploadedFile = "/Images/Orders/thumb-" + responseJSON.uploadedFile;
          $("#uploadedImage").attr("src", uploadedFile);
          $("#ImageErrorMessage").text("");
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the VALUMS code within `$(document).ready(function () { // here });`

and keep it under the `<HEAD>` tag. That's it!